# Flattening two arrays of date ranges in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, datetime, data-structures

I am building an availability calendar. This is a monthly view, and days are essentially a boolean, they can be either available or unavailable. There are multiple "products" that can exist on the calendar. Relatively simple.

I store these "availability ranges" as an array of objects to be as terse as possible. So a possible data set for a single product looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-08",
    "endDate": "2016-11-08"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-11",
    "endDate": "2016-11-14"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-20",
    "endDate": "2016-11-22"
  }
]
```

The UI looks very similar to this calendar:

[image]

The real trouble comes when users update their availability. They have the choice to "update all" or "update one". For example, if Room 1 was already unavailable on January 5th, and the user now wants to make all rooms unavailable from January 1st to January 10th, I need to remove the Room 1 January 5th object from the array, because it overlaps with the new data.

Additionally, I'd like to merge any timespans that are contiguous, eg:

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-08",
    "endDate": "2016-11-08"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-09",
    "endDate": "2016-11-09"
  },
]
```

Should be merged to:

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-08",
    "endDate": "2016-11-09"
  },
]
```

**I realise this is a relatively complex question, but surely there must be a pre-existing solution, or at least something similar?**

I have access to momentJs.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the **Fastest** approach, but a good place to start would be to make use of the [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to normalize the data by date so that any sequential dates will be next to each other, then use a simple array traversal to coalesce sequential dates.

The example below works with `sort` an array traversal.

```js
let states = [
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-08",
    "endDate": "2016-11-08"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-11",
    "endDate": "2016-11-14"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-20",
    "endDate": "2016-11-22"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-15",
    "endDate": "2016-11-19"
  },
];


console.log('Started With:', states);
 
let sorted_states = states.sort(function(a,b){
  return (new Date(a.startDate)) - (new Date(b.startDate))
});

// simple array traversal method
for (let i = sorted_states.length - 1; i--;){
  let current = sorted_states[i];
  let next = sorted_states[i+1];

  interval = ((new Date(next.startDate) - new Date(current.endDate)));
  if (interval <= (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)){ // one day
    newEntry = {
      startDate : current.startDate,
      endDate   : next.endDate,
    };
    sorted_states[i] = newEntry;
    sorted_states.splice(i+1, 1); // delete coalesced entry
  }
}

console.log('Ended With:', sorted_states)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function (ES6) you could use to merge two arrays, each containing periods. I applied it below to some sample data which is a bit more extended than the data you provided, so it covers several cases of overlapping and adjacency:

```js
function mergePeriods(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
        .sort( (a, b) => a.startDate.localeCompare(b.startDate) )
        .reduce( ([res, end], p) => 
            new Date(p.startDate).getTime()<=new Date(end).getTime()+90000000
                ? p.endDate > end
                    ? [res, res[res.length-1].endDate = p.endDate]
                    : [res, end]
                : [res.concat(p), p.endDate],
            [[], '1970-01-01'])[0];
}

// sample data
var unavailable1 = [
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-08",
    "endDate": "2016-11-08"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-11",
    "endDate": "2016-11-14"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-20",
    "endDate": "2016-11-22"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-27",
    "endDate": "2016-11-27"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-29",
    "endDate": "2016-11-29"
  }
];

var unavailable2 = [
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-09",
    "endDate": "2016-11-09"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-12",
    "endDate": "2016-11-15"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-18",
    "endDate": "2016-11-21"
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2016-11-26",
    "endDate": "2016-11-28"
  }
];

// merge the sample data
var res = mergePeriods(unavailable1, unavailable2);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

As a first step the two arrays are concatenated and sorted by increasing start date.

Then `reduce` is called on that array, with the start value (for the accumulator) equal to:

```
[[], '1970-01-01']
```

This pair consists of the array that will be accumulated to the final result (it starts empty), and the last encountered `endDate` date, which is set to a time long ago.

This pair is received in the `reduce` callback as `[res, end]`, and the current element from the array is named `p`. Then some comparisons are made to detect how the period `p` relates to `end`. In case of overlap are adjacency, the previous element in the current result is updated (extended) to match the `p.endDate`, which also becomes the new value of `end` in the next iteration.

In case there is a complete inclusion of `p` in the previous period, it is just ignored, and `[res, end]` are retained as they are.

If the period `p` is disjoint from the previous one, it is concatenated to the result (with `concat`) and the `end` is set to this `p.endDate`.

When the result is composed that way, and `reduce` returns, we are no longer interested in the latest end date, but only the array, which explains the final `[0]`.

## About 90000000

The value 90000000 represents the number of milliseconds in 25 hours. This is to detect if two periods are adjacent. 1 hour extra does not hurt, and will deal well with overnight DST changes. This could alternatively be done with `momentjs`, but this is not too cumbersome in plain JavaScript either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two objects as hash table for start and end dates and use use moments for getting the date of tomorrow and look if the date is a start date.

Then update the object, delete from start and end object, and register again.

This proposal works with unsorted data.

```js
function getTomorrow(day) {
    return moment(day).add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}

var array = [{ startDate: "2016-11-08", endDate: "2016-11-08" }, { startDate: "2016-11-09", endDate: "2016-11-09" }, { startDate: "2016-12-02", endDate: "2016-12-02" }, { startDate: "2016-12-03", endDate: "2016-12-03" }, { startDate: "2016-12-01", endDate: "2016-12-01" }, { startDate: "2016-12-04", endDate: "2016-12-04" }, ],
    start = {},
    end = {},
    result;

array.forEach(function (object) {
    start[object.startDate] = object;
    end[object.endDate] = object;
});

Object.keys(end).forEach(function (today) {
    var tomorrow = getTomorrow(today);
    if (start[tomorrow]) {
        end[today].endDate = start[tomorrow].endDate;
        end[tomorrow] = end[today];
        delete end[today];
        delete start[tomorrow];
    }
});

result = Object.keys(start).map(function (k) {
    return start[k];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isbetween` method from moment.
Design : after user selects a starting and end date , use his start date and compare it with each entry in your dates array (arr) if some entry has start date inside user selected range , delete it .After all entries are iterated upon , add user selected range to arr

```
userSdate="2016-11-08"
userEdate="2016-11-09"
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    tmpSdate = arr[i].startDate;
    tmpEdate = arr[i].endDate;
    console.log( tmpSdate + " : " + tmpEdate );
    isIn=moment(tmpSdate ).isBetween(userSdate,userEdate, null, '[]'); //note:[] means inclusive range
    if(isIn)
    {
      delete(arr[i]);//remove arr[i]
    }
}
arr.push({ "startDate": userSdate, "endDate" : userEdate});
```

Since delete doesn't reindex and update length property you might want to reindex it, though that's not mandatory.

Note that i have assumed there is no "range crossing" (when start of a range A lies completely inside range B but not it's(A) end does not) , see below

```
1                                      1
A-2------2----3----3--4----------4-----B            (no range crossing)
  C------D    E----F  G----------H

A--2------------------2--4--------------4---B           (range crossing)
   C-------3----------D  G--3-----------H
           E----------------F
```